# Google maps API: I Can only load my map once

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to track my location using HTML5 geolocation and the google maps API. I set everything up and I loaded my page the first time. It all seemed to work fine, the map was showing the area I expected and the marker was there as well.

Now, I've noticed something quite annoying whenever I use geolocation. I can load the map once without an issue. However, when i try to reload the page it is absolutely blank and it gives me no error in the console. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDFDGOMDXkdSHOkVaVbGjIwtMvqaTwVXCA"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var watchId, geocoder, startLat, startLong;
      var start = 1;

        window.onload = function(){

            if (navigator.geolocation){
                watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, onError, {maximumAge:60000, timeout:500000, enableHighAccuracy:true})
            }
      }
      function success(position){
          console.log('entered success')

          var currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
          var currentLong = position.coords.longitude;

          if (start === 1) {
              startLat = currentLat;
              startLong = currentLong;
              start = 0;
          }

          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLat, currentLong);

          geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlong}, function(result, status){
              if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                  document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = '<h2> Address is: ' + result[0].formatted_address + '</h2>'
              } else {
                  alert("Could not get the geolocation information")
              }
          });

          var mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLong),
              zoom: 10,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapArea"), mapOptions);

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLong),
              map: map,
              title: "My First Marker",
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
              //    other effect is BOUNCE
          });

      }

      function onError(error){
          console.log(error);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="location">

  </div>
  <div id="mapArea" style="height:500px;width:500px;"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT: added the network tab of DEV tools**

[image]

Comment: Can you look at the network tab in dev tools and see what you're getting back when you request the Google APIs map script? If you make dozens of requests to the same resource within an hour, you might be rate limited.

Comment: Is it asking you for location permission, after each refresh or can you see location permission denied for your page?

Comment: @NitishkumarSingh It only asks permission once and then never again.

Comment: @BoffinbraiN I added a screenshot of the network tab. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I should add that after a long time it does load what I want. I just don't understand why it takes so long.

Comment: @tilly can you try navigator.permission.query to verify that permission is granted to you, for more details follow link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/permissions

Comment: Yeah, it's likely that your geocoding queries are being rate-limited. When I tried getting mass geo-data a few years back for a hundred addresses, it took all night.